# Wrap Bootstrap Container in Single Col, 100% Height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the Bootstrap `.container` class to center content on the screen and fix it's width at something suitable for the viewport.  That's fine, however I now want to wrap that container in a single, centered column that has 100% height.  I want the height to be at least 100% of the viewport.  It should expand when the content does not fix on a single screen.

I have looked at general solutions that set the height of the `html` and `body` element to be at least the height of the screen, but these do not seem to work in Bootstrap.  I suspect it has something to do with box-sizing set to border-box.

Here is an example of the html:

```
<div class='my-col'>
  <div class='container'>
    <p>My content goes here</p>
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: use min-height:100vh for your container and why to keep container side col.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `min-height: 100vh`.

`vh` is a viewport unit: 1 vh is equal to 1% of the height of the display.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this really help you. I can't put a bootstrap in this fiddle, I just don't know how to do that. So will you please do this on your own console, i did this trick to get my content 100% height.

here we go:

```css
html{
margin:0;
height:100%;}
body{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
height:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
 background:yellow;
}

header{
flex:0 1 80px;
background:#ddd;
}
section#containerWrap{
flex:1 1 auto;
height:100%;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
flex-direction:column;
 background:#ccc;
 position:relative;
}
section#containerWrap .container{
height:100%;}
footer{
flex:0 1 40px;
  background:#999;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>header is about nav and logo</header>
<section id="containerWrap">
  <div class="container">
    <p>very long content should be flexible in here</p>
    <p>very long content should be flexible in here</p>
    <p>very long content should be flexible in here</p>
  </div>
</section>
<footer>the footer, website map, and more like contact us</footer>
</body>
```

it will set your footer absolutely in the bottom of the screen, you don't need to set the footer it self to position absolute or fixed what i did is, i stretch the container and take the rest of the height from header and footer.

maybe i can say it something like this

```
container height - (header height + footer height).
```

wish it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this code for your problem

```css
body,html{
  height:100%;
}

.my-col{
  height:100%;
  background:green;
}

.container{
  height:100%;
  background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.css" />
<div class='my-col'>
  <div class='container'>
    <p>My content goes here</p>
  </div>
</div
```

have a look on codepen also

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyObgP#anon-login